# Non-grouped or non-aggregated column in mysql select query

Tags: sql, mysql

I was checking solutions for this [leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/managers-with-at-least-5-direct-reports/). I came across the following MySQL solution:

```
Select m.name
from employee as e
inner join employee as m
on e.managerId=m.id
group by e.managerId 
having count(e.id)>=5
```

This query ran without any errors. from what I know, the above query should have thrown an error because the select has a non-grouped or non-aggregated column. Why is this behavior observed?

Comment: Focus on the 2nd part of Bill Karwin's excellent answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: @Shadow duplicate question's answer doesn't apply here.  assuming id is a not null unique key, m.name is guaranteed to only have one value for each group, and mysql 5.7+ is smart enough to know that and allow it, even with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.

Comment: Yes, it does apply as it explains functional dependency and that's the key bit here. If no pk or unique key were involved, them mysql could not work out functional dependency